# Betraying her boyfriend "was/is" what she did - what is the difference?

Tags: tense, past-tense, be-verb

**Example 1**

> Betraying her boyfriend **is** what she did.

**Example 2**

> Betraying her boyfriend **was** what she did.

What is the difference in meaning?

Answer (score 2):

This is slightly tricky to explain. As a general rule, '*is*' is for the present tense and '*was*' is for the past tense. But your example is something of an exception - the person is *presently* defining something that happened in the past.

This could mean there is no 'right' or 'wrong' choice - it may be a matter of perspective. For example, let's say you use an object for an alternative purpose - like using a mug as a plant pot. You could say "it *is* a mug", because that's what it is; but you wouldn't be incorrect to say that it '*was*' a mug, because you don't use it as a mug anymore.

The choice in your own example could depend on the perspective - are you simply describing past events, or is the focus on defining the past action? Personally, I think it is the latter, because the simple way to speak about the past event would be to say "*she betrayed her boyfriend*".

Comment: Example 1 is that i am presently defining a past event? Example 2 is that i was simply telling a past event and it can also mean defining a past event in a past perspective?

Comment: @vincentlin not quite - I'm saying they essentially mean the same thing but with a slightly different focus. I said it was tricky to explain! Consider another example - let's say you were commenting on a new book you just read about a historic tragedy. If you said "it *is* awful" you could mean that "it" is the book, or the account. If you said "it *was* awful" you would be referring to the tragedy. Ultimately, the same meaning. With your example, the past tense focuses on that single past event whereas using the present tense could be seen as a focus more on how you view it now.

Comment: @vincentlin Another example - in a court room where a killing is being judged as either murder or manslaughter, you might hear "it *is* murder" because a past action is being compared **now** against the legal definition of murder, but you might also hear "it *was* murder" in reference to the past action and the intent at the time.